# what kind of information can we get from pca?

Tags: pca

I have a large data set with many features, I want to know which ones are more important.  I know there are some features selection method, but I am wondering does pca say some thing about it? for example if the coefficient of first component of a variable is larger then it has meaning?

Answer (score 0):

PCA doesn't give you information about individual features *per se*, but you can plot the projection of the features onto PCA space, [much like Anh Lee does in his pokemon data analysis](https://anhqle.github.io/gotta-plot-them-all/), to get an idea of which features contribute most to the variance.

EDIT: You might also find [this](https://juliasilge.com/blog/stack-overflow-pca/) interesting.

Comment: could you please give me more information? which plot? is that work when I have 130 variables?

Comment: In that blog post I link, it is the result of the `biplot` command.